# How to make a following class into XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net, class, properties

So I am making this class in vb.net. This class will be serialized into a xml.

by using

> < XmlElement("Cookies")> _

I can name the elements the way I want it to be.

```
  Private i_cookies As Integer
<XmlElement("Cookies")> _
Public Property Cookies() As Integer
    Get
        Return i_cookies 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        i_cookies = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The elements are easy to name. But the thing is that i now need to do something to make a sequence containing the elements and complextype containing the sequence and also name them appropriately.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

I keep thinking that I need to put my properties(which are the elements) into something(but I don't know what) to represent as sequence and the sequence into something that represents as complextype.

Edit: I really have no idea how to formulate my question properly.

Edit(More information requested):
Below is the information on the way i want it to be, but the problem is that, i dont know how to add complextype and the sequence around the element and within the root in my class.

```
<root>
 <complexType name ="ShoppingList">
   <sequence>
     <element name="cookies"></element>
     ''More elements/product and such, but this isn't that difficult
   </sequence>
 </complexType>
<root>
```

Comment: Could you show the part of the class your having trouble with and what you want the XML to look like? I think that would make it easier to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @Kratz I have added more information regarding my Xml formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact structure you are trying to model. Here are some examples:

---

```
<ShoppingList>
    <Cookies>3</Cookies>
</ShoppingList>
```

is modeled by

```vb
<XmlType("ShoppingList")> _
Public Class ShoppingList
    <XmlElement("Cookies")> _
    Public Property Cookies As Integer
End Class
```

---

```xml
<ShoppingList>
    <Cookies>
        <Cookie>Chocolate Chip Cookies</Cookie>
        <Cookie>Brownies</Cookie>
    </Cookies>
</ShoppingList>
```

is modeled by

```vb
<XmlType("ShoppingList")> _
Public Class ShoppingList
    <XmlArray("Cookies")> _
    Public Property Cookies As List(Of Cookie)
End Class

Public Class Cookie
    <XmlText> _
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

or

```vb
<XmlType("ShoppingList")> _
Public Class ShoppingList
    <XmlArray("Cookies")> _
    <XmlArrayItem("Cookie")> _
    Public Property Cookies As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I wasn't really sure how to ask this properly. Thank you!